# After using "ionic run android" to deploy the app to phone, still exists the cross-domain?

Tags: angular, web-applications, ionic2, cross-domain, jsonp

When I was developing webapp with ionic2, I tested in Chrome. And I was in trouble with the cross-domain problem. Because I run the front-end in "ionic serve", and the port is 8100; I run the back-end in Spring-boot, and the port is 8080. Though I used JSONP to solve the problem, but I doubt that will this problem still exists when I deploy to phone, and back-end deploy to public Internet? And if it exists, what's the method to solve this usually?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port of your ionic project (offcourse backend also) you can add a cross request allow parameter in config.xml.(google it) try it i will work in mob also.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**, Cross domain issue will not be there when running on device. also, you can use this extension to avoid this issue when developing with chrome
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en